# How to make netbeans idea run faster on windows 10?

Tags: java, windows, netbeans

I got a limited resources laptop, I got to use NetBeans for a project, I am asking for tips to increase NetBeans's performance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't invest time in optimizing your NB installation as long as you can scale vertically: get a SSD (and faster hardware in general).

Also:

Add an exception for all relevant folders (e.g. project dir, temp dir) to your anti virus software (or better, get rid of it).
Don't use network drives for your projects
check if your home drive is local
check if your IDE uses non-local folders (e.g. %AppData%)

Comment: Thanks for your answer